# Which version of drupal should I study, 6 or 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-7

I have been planning to try to build a shopping store with Drupal 7 just for fun and have been studying it for a few days now. But with its current status(alpha5), I *doubt* if my time and effort would be worthwhile. If I use 6, I am afraid I can't apply my experience with it to 7 because, you know, the latter is way way better and different. Could you please give me an advice as to how should I approach this? Given I stick with 7, which aspects of development I should focus for now until the final release comes? Waiting for the final release before studying isn't an option because I couldn't find any better things to do other than this on my spare time.

Comment: Do you really want to be locked in to a specific version of a specific framework for site development?  I recommend you study and work on building your own site, using any random programming language and jQuery.

Comment: Sadly, I am too new to site development to do that and I am too confused to pick a framework from which I could benefit the most...so I could make my own... :-(

Comment: @Fosco: You'll have a much easier time building websites with Drupal than you will with jQuery. It's a CMS/CMF after all and not a JavaScript library.

Comment: @googletorp: yeah I know what it is, I just can't stand it.  It's my opinion that the learning curve could be better spent on homegrown development.

Comment: @Fosco: It really depends on what you want to do. You'll never be able to get the Drupal developer jobs, if you pick and random programming language and do whatever with it.

Comment: @googletorp: that's one of the things that motivated me to study Drupal. The higher rate of pay compared to developing with WP.

Comment: You don't get the luxury of 'homegrown development' on a deadline.

Comment: Happy release day! Drupal is no longer alpha or even beta. While your project may not be perfect, I don't know the state of ubercart in D7 yet, D7 itself is more than ready to roll.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Drupal 7 only has on this time of writing 40 critical bugs left, which means that it's pretty close to rc-1. This means that Drupal 7 is not all that unstable, the APIs should be in place etc. So you shouldn't expect any major changes from now on, only bug fixes etc.

This doesn't mean that you should use Drupal 7 for production sites, but you actually could if you don't do fancy stuff etc. So you could start learning Drupal with Drupal 7.

One thing you have to think about though, is that Drupal 7 doesn't have all the modules available that Drupal 6 has, and it will probably take some time even after Drupal 7 is released, before all the major modules have been ported. So unless you can wait developing for quite some time, Drupal 6 might not be a bad place to start. Integrating with modules is also a bit part of developing with Drupal and that's something you also will have a hard time doing with D7 for now.

Another thing to take into consideration, is that the API is not changing that much like it did from D5 to D6, so starting with Drupal 6 is not a bad place at all. A lot of the stuff that's new in Drupal 7 is not APIs you'll be using for simple sites.

### Conclusion

You can start developing with Drupal 7 now, but you might have an easier time and learn more if you start with Drupal 6. The changes will be small and you should be able to adjust without problems.

Comment: A newcomer may not realize how important it is to have a solid collection of contributed modules. At last count I use over 70 of them at various times to construct sites, and I don't think that's an unusually high number.

Comment: I agree with keith. Modules like token, imagecache, views etc are very useful and can be easily controlled with their apis. That said a lot of the important ones are core now aren't they?

Comment: It's only image api and fields that's in core now.

Answer (score 0):

Contine with 6 for now and keep upto date with whats new in 7 on the surface level. I dont dig deep into new releases until they hit beta 2 mark by the time which they become more stable. Alpha builds are too early to track and will probably waste ur time configuring than learning... Enjoy!!!

Answer (score 0):

As long as 7 is still in alpha versions, it's pretty likely to change.  Anything you learn about 6 will stay relevant to the industry for quite some time, yet.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't study the code line for line, but try to grasp the fundamentals of Drupal and how it all ties together. Then your knowledge will transcend versions, so you don't fret over API changes to the node system.

Plus, the API is -right- there for you to refer to and is always updated.